# Saving VBA code as a separate file in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very complex Excel workbook, with an awful lot of VBA code and macros in it. For version control purposes, I'd really like to be able to save the code as separate files to the workbook proper - to split it off into modules. Is this a thing that's remotely possible?

Comment: Yes, but this question is too broad.  Check out [this resource](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx) for an introduction/tutorial to programming the VBE.  For example, Yes, you can programmatically export all code modules to a folder, and then import to a new file, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should also look into Add-ins (.xlam). These allow your modules/class modules to be referenced in other workbooks. If you deploy a tool to a workgroup then realize that you need to change a macro you can update the .xlam and it gets pushed to all workbooks that reference it.